# getHyperlink doesn't exist on a Cell Object

Tags: java, jxl

I did lot of searches, none has the same case;

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Hyperlink;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;Workbook workbook = null;
..
..
..
//lot of code
..
Workbook workbook = null;

    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Nouveau dossier\\file.xls"));
        for (int nsheet = 0; nsheet < 5; nsheet ++){
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(nsheet);
            Cell structure = sheet.getCell(0,0);
            Hyperlink h = structure.getHyperlink();
            }
        }
```

I have an error telling me that getHyperlink is not a method on the object Cell ... 
I'm using Eclipse Neon, with jxl.jat*r downloaded from http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ and it's the latest one.

Comment: microsoft office version ? That link says >Reads data from Excel 95, 97, 2000, XP, and 2003 workbooks

Comment: Seems this lib is quiet old. Try https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is [Cell.getHyperlink()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getHyperlink%28%29) which is in apache [poijar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoi39jar.htm)

jxl will support .doc extension files only and you can read only limited rows(256) and columns(256).In jxl jar you have to get it as [HyperLink[]](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getHyperlinks()) arrays from sheet.

```
public Hyperlink[] getHyperlinks()


Gets the hyperlinks on this sheet

Returns: an array of hyperlinks
```

Better Using apache poi  you can read all type of document extensions. Change all you imports to apache poi jar classes and try.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, about returned values; my links references to other sheets, how could I get it properly? I don't know how to procede.

Comment: @BiLLiXx The property you are looking for is the location, however there is a isLocation() and setLocation() but no getLocation()